# Ensure evenly distributed hashing in HashSet, how does it work?

Tags: java, hash

Here is an example from Intro to Java Programming (Liang):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MyHashSet<E> implements MySet<E> {
  // Define the default hash table size. Must be a power of 2
  private static int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

  // Define the maximum hash table size. 1 << 30 is same as 2^30
  private static int MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1 << 30; 

  // Current hash table capacity. Capacity is a power of 2
  private int capacity;

  // Define default load factor
  private static float DEFAULT_MAX_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75f; 

  // Specify a load factor threshold used in the hash table
  private float loadFactorThreshold; 

  // The number of entries in the set
  private int size = 0; 

  // Hash table is an array with each cell that is a linked list
  private LinkedList<E>[] table;

  /** Construct a set with the default capacity and load factor */
  public MyHashSet() {  
    this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY, DEFAULT_MAX_LOAD_FACTOR);    
  }

  /** Construct a set with the specified initial capacity and 
   * default load factor */
  public MyHashSet(int initialCapacity) { 
    this(initialCapacity, DEFAULT_MAX_LOAD_FACTOR);    
  }

  /** Construct a set with the specified initial capacity 
   * and load factor */
  public MyHashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactorThreshold) { 
    if (initialCapacity > MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
      this.capacity = MAXIMUM_CAPACITY;
    else
      this.capacity = trimToPowerOf2(initialCapacity);

    this.loadFactorThreshold = loadFactorThreshold;    
    table = new LinkedList[capacity];
  }

  /** Remove all elements from this set */ 
  public void clear() {
    size = 0;
    removeElements();
  }

  /** Return true if the element is in the set */
  public boolean contains(E e) {
    int bucketIndex = hash(e.hashCode());
    if (table[bucketIndex] != null) {
      LinkedList<E> bucket = table[bucketIndex]; 
      for (E element: bucket)
        if (element.equals(e)) 
          return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  /** Add an element to the set */
  public boolean add(E e) {
    if (contains(e)) 
      return false;

    if (size > capacity * loadFactorThreshold) {
      if (capacity == MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
        throw new RuntimeException("Exceeding maximum capacity");

      rehash();
    }

    int bucketIndex = hash(e.hashCode());

    // Create a linked list for the bucket if it is not created
    if (table[bucketIndex] == null) {
      table[bucketIndex] = new LinkedList<E>();
    }

    // Add e to hashTable[index]
    table[bucketIndex].add(e);

    size++; // Increase size

    return true;
  }

  /** Remove the element from the set */
  public boolean remove(E e) {
    if (!contains(e))
      return false;

    int bucketIndex = hash(e.hashCode());

    // Create a linked list for the bucket if it is not created
    if (table[bucketIndex] != null) {
      LinkedList<E> bucket = table[bucketIndex]; 
      for (E element: bucket)
        if (e.equals(element)) {
          bucket.remove(element);
          break;
        }
    }

    size--; // Decrease size

    return true;
  }

  /** Return true if the set contains no elements */
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
  }

  /** Return the number of elements in the set */
  public int size() {
    return size;
  }

  /** Return an iterator for the elements in this set */
  public java.util.Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new MyHashSetIterator(this);
  }

  /** Inner class for iterator */
  private class MyHashSetIterator implements java.util.Iterator<E> {
    // Store the elements in a list
    private java.util.ArrayList<E> list;
    private int current = 0; // Point to the current element in list
    MyHashSet<E> set;

    /** Create a list from the set */
    public MyHashSetIterator(MyHashSet<E> set) {
      this.set = set;
      list = setToList();
    }

    /** Next element for traversing? */
    public boolean hasNext() {
      if (current < list.size())
        return true;

      return false;
    }

    /** Get the current element and move cursor to the next */
    public E next() {
      return list.get(current++);
    }

    /** Remove the current element and refresh the list */
    public void remove() {
      // Delete the current element from the hash set
      set.remove(list.get(current)); 
      list.remove(current); // Remove the current element from the list
    }
  }  

  /** Hash function */
  private int hash(int hashCode) {
    return supplementalHash(hashCode) & (capacity - 1);
  }

  /** Ensure the hashing is evenly distributed */
  private static int supplementalHash(int h) {
    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
  }

  /** Return a power of 2 for initialCapacity */
  private int trimToPowerOf2(int initialCapacity) {
    int capacity = 1;
    while (capacity < initialCapacity) {
      capacity <<= 1;
    }

    return capacity;
  }

  /** Remove all e from each bucket */
  private void removeElements() {
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
      if (table[i] != null) {
        table[i].clear();
      }
    }
  }

  /** Rehash the set */
  private void rehash() {
    java.util.ArrayList<E> list = setToList(); // Copy to a list
    capacity <<= 1; // Double capacity      
    table = new LinkedList[capacity]; // Create a new hash table
    size = 0;

    for (E element: list) {
      add(element); // Add from the old table to the new table
    }
  }

  /** Copy elements in the hash set to an array list */
  private java.util.ArrayList<E> setToList() {
    java.util.ArrayList<E> list = new java.util.ArrayList<E>();

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
      if (table[i] != null) {
        for (E e: table[i]) {
          list.add(e);
        }
      }
    }  

    return list;
  }

  /** Return a string representation for this set */
  public String toString() {
    java.util.ArrayList<E> list = setToList();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("[");

    // Add the elements except the last one to the string builder
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
      builder.append(list.get(i) + ", ");
    }

    // Add the last element in the list to the string builder
    if (list.size() == 0)
      builder.append("]");
    else
      builder.append(list.get(list.size() - 1) + "]");

    return builder.toString();
  }
}
```

I don't quite follow this part:

```
  /** Ensure the hashing is evenly distributed */
  private static int supplementalHash(int h) {
    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
  }
```

The operations are all clear, but how do they thus ensure evenly distributed hashing?

Another question about this code, in this part:

```
  /** Add an element to the set */
  public boolean add(E e) {
    if (contains(e)) 
      return false;

    if (size > capacity * loadFactorThreshold) {
      if (capacity == MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
        throw new RuntimeException("Exceeding maximum capacity");

      rehash();
    }

    int bucketIndex = hash(e.hashCode());

    // Create a linked list for the bucket if it is not created
    if (table[bucketIndex] == null) {
      table[bucketIndex] = new LinkedList<E>();
    }

    // Add e to hashTable[index]
    table[bucketIndex].add(e);

    size++; // Increase size

    return true;
  }
```

Why not put the size checking and rehashing block after `size++`?

Comment: Similar, but actually very different questions.

Comment: You asked "The operations are all clear, but how do they thus ensure evenly distributed hashing?" - that is explained in the answers.  If it isn't sufficiently answered then it might be helpful to narrow your question a bit.

Comment: No deterministic hash function can, by itself, ensure an "even distribution" over buckets, so the implementation comment is (strictly speaking) incorrect. The motivation for post-processing the hash value in this way is explained in the linked question (simply speaking, it compensates for shortcomings of a particular kind of hash function)

Answer (score 2):

> The operations are all clear, but how do they thus ensure evenly distributed hashing?

It doesn't, it is a simple effort to arrange the bits randomly esp the lower bits so you have a reasonably random arrangement of bits without too much complexity.

Unfortunately it fails to consider that shift is actually an expensive operation esp when there is more than one of them, it can stall the CPU pipeline.  You can get good results with multiplication and addition and perhaps one shift and it will be faster.  Multiplication and Add can also improve the randomness of higher bits.

Note: the lower bits will be `^` between nine bits in total from the input hash, however the top bits, esp the highest 4 will be unchanged by this process.

This isn't such a problem as the hash() will either mask the lower bits (as it does here) or use `%` which is more expensive but again only needs reasonably random lower bits assuming the modulus is not too large.

> Why not put the size checking and rehashing block after size++?

Resizing is expensive and you could add the element and then resize it, but this would mean adding the element which triggers a resize twice (before the resize and as part of the resize process)